# Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit won't play DVDs

Tags: 12.04, video, 64-bit, dvd

I have a Lenovo T400 with an Intel Cenrino 2 vPro prcessor and I am running Ubuntu 12.04 64bit. For the most part, everything is running great, but I have one problem. For some reason I can not play DVDs at all. I am able to play all other video formats with no problem, but when it comes to DVDs, I keep getting an input/output error. I have tried about a dozen DVDs and still come up with the same problem. I can play CDs with absolutely no problem. I also have all the needed drivers and such needed to play DVDs. Am I the only one with this problem? And is this fixable? And How?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You have to install libdvdcss:

1. `sudo apt-get install libdvdread4`
2. `sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh`

Reference: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs

Comment: I did that. I even tried resetting the region code as well with no success. If worse comes to worse, I can always do a full reinstall and start from scratch...

Comment: Link more recent: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats#Playing_Restricted_Formats

Comment: No use... 32 bit works fine, but 64-bit won't play DVDs... Even after installing libdvdread4 and setting it up. I have even re downloaded and re installed it several times... Still same problem... Could it be a 64-bit ISO error?

Comment: Can't you play ANY video DVDs or just the copy protected ones? What about data DVDs, can you read them?

Comment: Try MD5ing the ISO you downloaded. If only a few bytes are wrong, most of Ubuntu will work (installation, major programs) but some parts that don't pop up very often may be messed up.